# Is it time to nominate pro-tem moderators as soon as we're out of our 7 day private beta?

Tags: discussion, support, beta, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pro-tem moderator nominations](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106/pro-tem-moderator-nominations)

On travel.SE I remember bringing this up and the contributors said "oh no it's too early" but then word came from Stack Exchange "yep you should be doing this already". But I forget how soon I asked.

I have a couple of people I'd like to nominate, is now the time or should we wait another week or what?

Comment: This is odd. You asked if it's time to start nominations and then answered "yes." Why not just *start* the thread itself? #6 in http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/

Comment: I answered it two hours later when I got around to digging up the facts, which I couldn't remember off-hand. (I'm currently hitchhiking around the world and had an unreliable connection and lots of windows open) Also after the reaction on travel I thought it's better to mention it here and see if anybody had anything to say before jumping right in.

Comment: OK I've nominated two people I've had in mind since I've been involved in the beta that I'm impressed with: See here: **[Pro-tem moderator nominations](http://meta.linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/106/pro-tem-moderator-nominations)**

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate, per se, but might as well make it easy to redirect people to the nomination thread.

Answer (score 1):

[As answered by Robert Cartaino when we asked on travel.SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158/pro-tem-moderators-is-it-time-to-start-nominations-yet/159#159) the pro-tems are appointed at about two weeks in. We are now past one week in so I think we should begin the process over this week to be ready for it.