# Pro-tem moderator nominations

Tags: discussion, beta, moderation, votes

Well we've been around more than a week and are now open to the public. Stack Exchange likes to appoint pro-tem moderators at about the two week mark so it's high time to nominate some contributors for those positions.

Please nominate one user per answer so that we can vote up/down each person individually.

Include a brief reason why you're nominating them.

Feel free to nominate yourself, Stack Exchange apparently specifically encourages this.

Don't be shy to vote. Vote up people you think ask good questions, submit good answers, do other kinds of constructive work on the site. Vote down people you think are not so appropriate.

---

According to [this page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), these points must be included in the question.

### How Moderators are Appointed Pro Tem

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active,
  consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s
  community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and
  respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Answer (score 7):

[**Aaron**](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/46/aaron)

He's studying linguistics and seems to be able to come up with answers to questions after others comment that they're too hard to answer. And they're good answers! Good linguistics and easy to read for those of us who are not real linguists.

(edit by LouisRhys): Plus he is one of the most active and most sensible users on meta. I believe he is the most suited to assume a position of leadership in this SE

Comment: Thanks hippie and Louis.  I will accept the nomination – glad to do my part in building the community here.

Answer (score 3):

[hippietrail](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/51/hippietrail)

He is the most active contributor (29q + 8a!), and the highest-scored member in our SE. He also appears to be very responsive and "online" very often. Plus he cares a lot about the development of this site and one of the most active members on meta.

Comment: Thanks Louis. I will accept of course though as a mere armchair linguist I'm underqualified (-:

Comment: @hippie Hey, I don't think the main thing is whether you're a good linguist or a good answerer or not.. The main thing is how well you can perform the moderator duty and responsibility. It is a moderator position, not "master answerer" position

Answer (score 3):

[Louis Rhys](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/92/louis-rhys)

I think he deserves a mention, considering his good Q&A/Reputation ratio: with only 14 questions and 4 answers he reached a fairly high reputation, which means he proposes quality questions and provides good answers.

Comment: Thank you for the surprising nomination :) If selected I will be very glad to contribute :)

Comment: I'm bad at remembering names in real life and terrible on the Internet but now I can see I recognize the same qualities in Louis's contributions (-:

Answer (score 2):

[**Steven Xu**](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/9/steven-xu)

To me he seems to offer the best real linguistic answers on the site. Plus of course he had the highest reputation for almost the whole beta run so he must be doing something right (-:

Answer (score 2):

**[Alenanno](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/users/111/alenanno)**

I've seen him doing maintenance of questions and answers on the site; this is in addition to his participation in the form of questions and answers.  He engages well with other community members in comments as well as here on meta.

Comment: I have been a bit puzzled by the wording of some of his questions but he's easy to talk to on chat and definitely is working hard on the site.

Comment: @hippietrail Eheh I'll try to pay more attention next time. :) Thanks for the nomination! I'm not sure how it works, the most voted ones are elected?

Comment: @Alenanno: I don't know the exact criteria but the votes here are definitely a factor. I guess they take their own look at what each nominated contributor has done too.

Comment: @hippietrail The I suppose that all that's left to do is to wait. :)

Comment: Well wait and nominate anybody else conspicuously doing a good job to improve the site! (-:

Comment: If I find someone else, I will :)